# Filter Data Table using drop down box in Dash / Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using Python and Dash to create an interactive web app. I have created a simple table to display all players and generic stats, but I would like a way to filter the table using a drop down so can just select players in a certain team.

The dropdown function is working, but I am really struggling with the data table and the callback. I understand you can filter in the header (which his what all the tutorials I have found demonstrate), but I really want it to update the table using the callback method as will help with what I need to do down the line.

Here is a link to my excel data if needed

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1roAfiXIvR_nj6IrNOuYGfkZC7-vsTl2_/view?usp=sharing

My current code is:

```
    import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

import os
import pathlib

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

navy = '#06122F'
blue = '#0074D9'
gb_blue = '#004373'
red = '#C51E42'
light_grey = '#F6F6F6'
#=-----------------------

df = pd.read_excel('Box Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Player Stats')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#--------------------------------
#group by team and then take an average of the advanced stats
df = df.groupby(['Player', 'Team'])[['#', 'MIN', 'PTS', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG%']].mean()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)


app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Label('Select Team'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='select_team',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Team'].unique()],
        value=[i for i in df['Team']],
        searchable=True,
        style={'width':'75%'}
        ),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='general_stats',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': blue,
            'fontWeight': 'bold',
            'color': 'white',
            'border': '0px'
        },
        style_cell={'padding': '5px', 'border': '0px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
            'backgroundColor': light_grey,
            'if':{
                'filter_query': '{Team}= "TEAM SOLENT KESTRELS"' #filter to display our team
            },
            'backgroundColor': red,
            'color': 'white'
        }
        ],
        style_cell_conditional=[
        {
        'if': {'column_id': c},
            'textAlign': 'left'
        } for c in ['Player', 'Team']
        ],
        style_as_list_view=True,
        page_action='native',
        fixed_rows={'headers':True},
        style_table={'height': '400px', 'overflowY': 'auto'},
        sort_action='native',
    )

])

@app.callback(
    [Output('general_stats', 'data')],
    [Input(component_id='select_team', component_property='value')]
)


def update_table(option_selected):
    filtered_df = df[df.Team != option_selected]

    return(filtered_df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: what is the exact problem? I see you're returning a df to the data field of your datatable. But in the html your usinf df.to_dict(). Plus you're filtering the df by team != option which will show the players not from that team.

Comment: if im honest I am stumbling through the def in the callback and have only got that far based on what I have researched, but might be completely wrong. I basically want to filter the table based the team that is selected in the dropdown (so will change the code to == instead of !=). I get a error message saying dash.exceptions.invalidcallbackreturnvalue...... is a multi-output. excepted the output type to be a list or tuple but got....... (and it shows the df)

Comment: oh that's because in your callback decorator you put the output in a list. Either remove that list or return [filtereddf..to_dict(records)]

Comment: Amazing, works! Thanks for your help, was closer to the right code than I thought. For anyone that comes across this, the final code was `def update_table(option_selected):
    filtered_df = df[df.Team == option_selected]

    return[filtered_df.to_dict('records')]`